# toString with JSON Object

Tags: json, groovy

when creating a string from a JSON object, it is constructing the resulting string like this

```
"comments": "[
 {\"id\":2,
  \"postType\":\"COMMENT_TYPE\",
  \"subject\":\"RE: sadasds\",
  \"body\":\"test comment submission\",
  \"tags\":\"\",
  \"media\":[],
  \"comments\":\"[]\"}
]"
```

including the `\"` which makes it difficult for me to include in an existing JSON object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to explain the situation you're in, and the code you're using

I just tried this:

```
@Grab( group='net.sf.json-lib', module='json-lib', version='2.3', classifier='jdk15')
import net.sf.json.*

def o = [integer:1, bool: true] as JSONObject 
println o.toString()
```

And it (as expected) gave me the output:

```
{"integer":1,"bool":true}
```

What version of Groovy are you using?  Which JSON library are you using?